# Calculating an average of multiple random numbers Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I am fairly new to Python and have run into a roadblock with trying to calculate an average of a bunch of random numbers.The general overview of the program is that it is a die rolling program which prompts the user to enter a certain amount of sides and it then rolls until the program outputs snake eyes. It also keeps track of the amount of doubles rolled and how long it took to get snake eyes. Then create an average of the numbers that were rolled for each die throughout the program. This is where I am lost.

EDIT: I deleted my original code and worked in Vasilis's answer:

```
import random

while True:
    #prompts user for valid number
    user_s = int (input ("How many sides on your dice? "))
    if user_s < 3:
         print("That is not a valid size value, please enter a positive number")
    if user_s >= 3:
        break

print()
print("Thanks! Here we go...")
print()
double_count = 0 
roll_count = 0

sum1 = 0 # Used to calculate sum of die_1
sum2 = 0 # Used to calculate sum of die_2

while True:
    roll_count += 1
    die_1 = random.randint(1,user_s)   
    die_2 = random.randint (1,user_s)




    print(roll_count,".", " Die number 1 is ", die_1 , " and die number 2 is ", die_2,  ".", sep ="")
    if die_1 == die_2:
        double_count += 1
    if die_1 == 1 and die_2 == 1:
        break

    # Making sum
    sum1 = sum1 + die_1 
    sum2 = sum2 + die_2

print("You finally got snake eyes on try number", roll_count)
print("Along the way you rolled a double", double_count,"times")

print(die_1)
print(die_2)

# Integer divisions

avg_roll1 = sum1 // roll_count
avg_roll2 = sum2 // roll_count


print("The average roll for die 1 was", format(avg_roll1,".2f"))
print("The average roll for die 2 was", avg_roll2)
```

However like he pointed out it doesn't take all of the numbers that is recorded through all the rolls, rather the last number. 
Any help to accomplish that would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A few things:  A `list` will never be equal to an integer.  `die_1 = [random.randint(1,user_s)]` isn't appending to a list, it's just replacing it.  If you want to *keep* the old values (which you've correctly figured out that you do), you'll need to add to the list, not replace it.  Finally, since `die_1` is already a list, `[die_1]` is a *list of lists*, so `sum` won't really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it myself.

Set the accumulator variable = to the die rolls. In this case sum1 and sum2 are the variables.

```
# make all of the functions in the "random" module available to this program
import random

while True:
    #prompts user for valid number
    user_s = int (input ("How many sides on your dice? "))
    if user_s < 3:
         print("That is not a valid size value, please enter a positive number")
    if user_s >= 3:
        break

print()
print("Thanks! Here we go...")
print()
double_count = 0 
roll_count = 0

sum1 = 0 # Used to calculate sum of die_1
sum2 = 0 # Used to calculate sum of die_2

#while statement for die rolls
while True:
    roll_count += 1
    die_1 = random.randint(1,user_s)
    sum1 += die_1

    die_2 = random.randint (1,user_s)
    sum2 += die_2




    print(roll_count,".", " Die number 1 is ", die_1 , " and die number 2 is ", die_2,  ".", sep ="")
    if die_1 == die_2:
        double_count += 1
    if die_1 == 1 and die_2 == 1:
        break



print("You finally got snake eyes on try number", roll_count)
print("Along the way you rolled a double", double_count,"times")


# Integer divisions

avg_roll1 = sum1 / roll_count

avg_roll2 = sum2 / roll_count


print("The average roll for die 1 was", format(avg_roll1,".2f"))
print("The average roll for die 2 was", format(avg_roll2,".2f"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes in your code if you like to take a look. I assumed that you wanted the average to be calculated as an integer although you can change that. You use `die_1` and `die_2` as simple integer variables and thus they hold only the last value generated by `random.randint(1,user_s)`:

```
import random

    '''Skipped input part'''

    print()
    print("Thanks! Here we go...")
    print()
    double_count = 0 
    roll_count = 0

    sum1 = 0 # Used to calculate sum of die_1
    sum2 = 0 # Used to calculate sum of die_2

    while True:
        roll_count += 1
        die_1 = random.randint(1,user_s)   
        die_2 = random.randint (1,user_s)

        print("DIE_1: ", die_1)
        print("DIE_2: ", die_2)


        print(roll_count,".", " Die number 1 is ", die_1 , " and die number 2 is ", die_2,  ".", sep ="")
        if die_1 == die_2:
            double_count += 1
        if die_1 == 1 and die_2 == 1:
            break

        # Making sum
        sum1 = sum1 + die_1 
        sum2 = sum2 + die_2

    print("You finally got snake eyes on try number", roll_count)
    print("Along the way you rolled a double", double_count,"times")

    print(die_1)
    print(die_2)

    # Integer divisions

    avg_roll1 = sum1 // roll_count
    avg_roll2 = sum2 // roll_count


    print("The average roll for die 1 was", avg_roll1)
    print("The average roll for die 2 was", avg_roll2)
```